# SQL create new columns from row values by seperate

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to create new columns from row values seperated by , from TEAM colum. What is the easiest way to do it in SQL? I don't have unique ID, but this table might have more varchar2 columns not just these three...

```
TEAM      |   NAME     | AAA    |
---------------------------------
A1,A2,A3  |   JOHN     |   aaa  |
B1        |   JILL     |   sss  |
B2        |   JAMES    |   ddd  |
B3,B4     |   JOAN     |   ccc  |
```

Expected result:

```
TEAM      |   NAME     | AAA   |
---------------------------------
A1        |   JOHN     |  aaa  |   
A2        |   JOHN     |  aaa  |
A3        |   JOHN     |  aaa  |
B1        |   JILL     |  sss  |
B2        |   JAMES    |  ddd  |
B3        |   JOAN     |  ccc  |
B4        |   JOAN     |  ccc  |
```

I was trying with a solution like this:

```
    select
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n
```

..but I want to solve this problem without creating a new table.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "without creating a new table"? Do you want a view? The original table updated? Something else? "I want to create new columns" doesn't make sense to me. What do you expect to be added in the new columns for the row `A1,A2,A3  |   JOHN`?

Comment: You use regexp_substr to select the value in the sub-query.  See linked question

Comment: I see but it doesn't tell me after that how I can group it by the second column. @Hogan

Comment: @Tivi -- if you join to it then it will be fine -- cross join will auto magically work -- unless you have more than two columns.

Comment: @Hogan I have other columns but I did not show up them in the example.

Comment: @tivi -- do you have an ID column -- use that to join back to.

Comment: @Hogan All I have varchar columns so it makes this problem difficult (for me at least). That is why I am not sure if this problem is solvable with the linked question you attached.

Comment: @Hogan I think the OP wants actually to explode the comma-separated strings in column `TEAM` into multiple rows. The linked answer does not show how to do this. Hence, the question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate, at least not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @blackbishop -- that is exactly what the linked example does.

Comment: @tivi -- I'd suggest take a stab at using that answer to solve your problem -- if you can't create a new question that references that answer, shows what you tried that did not work, show exactly before and after expectations (as you did here) someone (maybe me) will show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Hogan I don't agree. The liked question is about how to filter a column using a *stringified* list which is not what the OP is looking for here. I agree on the question does not show much research effort nor a good explanation but it definitely not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I added more to the description but there's still not a proper and simple solution to solve this problem. Anyway thanks everyone who did not vote down this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a second table named `team` available which contains the teams listed uniquely, i. e. it has a column named `team` which has "A1" etc.  as its values, you could use

```
SELECT team.team, tablename.name
FROM team JOIN tablename
  ON ',' || tablename.team || ',' LIKE '%,' || team.team || ',%'
```

This works assuming the comma is not part of any team name, as it then searches if teh string of a single team name between commas is contained in the string ",A1,A2,A3," for your first record, and that should match fro all three teams, and hence produce three rows.

**Solution 2**

A second possibility would be to use a recursive query, I took it from [here](https://sodocumentation.net/oracle/topic/1968/splitting-delimited-strings) and adapted it to your table/column names:

```
WITH bounds ( name, list, start_pos, end_pos, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT name, team, 1, INSTR( team, ',' ), 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT name,
         list,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( list, ',', end_pos + 1 ),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT name,
       SUBSTR(
         list,
         start_pos,
         CASE end_pos
           WHEN 0
           THEN LENGTH( list ) + 1
           ELSE end_pos
         END - start_pos
       ) AS team,
      lvl
FROM   bounds;
```

The query named `bounds` in the `WITH` clause unpivots the records (i. e. you already have one record per team generated from the comma separated list, and it calculates the string positions of begin and end of the team names in the comma separated list, and tehn the main query just has to finish the result, and to extract the team name from the comma separated string.

Comment: I should solve this problem without creating a new table.

Comment: Ok, while my answer works in nearly all variants of SQL, then the answer can get a bit more specific to the SQL dialect, as it would partly depend on the available string functions. You tagged your question only 'SQL'. Could  you be more specific? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? Maybe you put the answer better below your main question than below my comment.

Comment: It works and thank you for your answer but that is not the solution for my question. (I already tagged my question with "oracle-apex" and "sql" tags.)

Comment: Ah, I was assuming Apex is just a frontend tool independent of the backend database, I found out otherwise now. Nevertheless, I added an Oracle solution (for newer Oracle versions that support recursive standard SQL syntax and not only the Oracle specific `CONNECTED BY` recursive queries)